# How to implement multi-thread callback-based processing of a network protocol with Twisted

Tags: multithreading, queue, twisted, deferred

I'm working on an application for handling a rather simple text-based protocol. So far I have:

1. A `ReconnectingClientFactory` that handles connections and leverages `MyProtocol` for actual initialization (the basic protocol boils down to negotiating some data, and then parsing of exchanged objects is done by a higher level API, which should override the `ReconnectingClientFactory`.
2. A `LineReceiver` class `MyProtocol` that handles said negotiation steps. Afterwards a single method will be called for processing any further packets coming from the other end.
3. The `LineReceiver` will call a method from the `ReconnectingClientFactory`, to parse the packet contents. This can be overridden by other classes which consume packets and handle responses.

Currently I'm not sure if this is the best approach to do what I want to implement, or even if `Deferreds` are the proper way to go about it.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish in a manner that follows Twisted's guidelines as closely as possible:

- A thread queue for processing packets, and properly deliver responses to these packets (they don't need to be sent immediately, timing is not critical).
- A consumer of packets that connects to the remote end using the `LineReceiver` protocol, and pushes packets that pass simple validation to the thread queue for processing. This way validation is done at the bare minimum level, and actual parsing is done in a queue. Note that responses to bad packets are not necessary, but a bonus. They do not need to happen "immediately".
- It would be nice if Twisted offered something to rate-limit processing, but this is not critical to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a thread queue for this?  This sounds very complex and is very abstract and a full answer could fill a book.  Please ask something more specific.

Comment: Do you suggest a more efficient design? I understand the question could be kind of vague for some people. The main issue is whether I should use deferreds or not, and if I can see any examples of existent protocols where parsing is done in a thread queue. The listener would have quite heavy traffic, and parsing some of the objects might involve math that I don't want to do in the main "networking" thread. Does that make sense?

Comment: If there is heavy processing to do, you will want to start a subprocess (with `reactor.spawnProcess`), as CPU-parallel work with threads is not possible in Python due to the global interpreter lock.  This is actually a good thing in disguise, because you should not be heavily using threads in applications :-).